# What is 'BloodLust', and how does it affect me?

Tags: seed-2-vortex-of-war

In [Seed 2: Vortex of War](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/seed-2-vortex-of-war/id383575711?mt=8), every now and then I'm lucky enough to pick up a rare(ish) weapon from combat.  Sometimes, these rare weapons have a stat bonus for something called *Bloodlust*, given as a percentage.  What is this?  And what is the percentage a measure of?

[image: This particular weapon has a bonus which says: "Bloodlust + 13%"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems it is the percentage of damage caused on enemy returning to you as health gain on hit.

So, when a hit causes 100 points of damage, health gained is 13 points, regarding the 13% stat above.

It is comparable to the "leeching" stat in games like Diablo.

Comment: Did you test this yourself?

Comment: If this **is** the case, what determines how often this effect 'happens' when in combat?

Comment: @Wipqozn No A friend of mine has the game on his iPhone, he confirmed the behaviour. @GnomeSlice It seems to happen every time you land a successful hit.

Comment: @Bora > I can tell you from experience that it does not happen every time a hit is landed on the enemy.  If that were the case, this would make you pretty much unstoppable anyway.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this user guide](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/114/1143169p1.html) on IGN Bloodlust heals you every time you hit an enemy.

From the relevant section:

> Weapons: more attack rating, critical
>   rating, **blood lust (hit heals you)**,
>   -mp/sp consumption, +mp/sp regen, -skill cooldown, +skill level

Comment: I had a hunch about this.  Can you find any more information on what the percentage value refers to?  Is it the amount healed?  Or the chance for a hit to heal?

Comment: No I can not. I searched for awhile both before and after I posted that (and more now), but that guide was the only source I found which even mentioned bloodlust. Only source I find which was anything other then a review in fact. If I do find anything, I'll make sure to update my answer.

Comment: If it is anything like other games, you will restore X percent of your base health on a kill. So if you have 100 base health, and kill a mob you should gain 13% of 100 = 13 HP.

Comment: @Sharken It's just as likely it's a percentage of damage done, or the health of the monster being attacked.

Comment: Or it could also be a percentage of how likely any given hit is to trigger the effect.  This is the issue. :P

Answer (score -3):

It means exactly what it states. The character lusts for blood. It’s basically another way of saying that the character is completely berserk and focused on killing its opponent. I also believe "bloodlust" gives a +percentage of your max health and a + value of hp and a slight decrease in defense.

**Bloodlust** is a desire for extreme violence and carnage, often aroused in the heat of battle and leading to uncontrolled slaughter and torture.

Comment: Good definition, but I was actually wondering how it relates to the game *Seed 2: Vortex of War*.  I don't think the game-related info you provided is correct, either.